# How to use jQuery with webpack before CDN link

Tags: jquery, webpack

Is it possible to load external jQuery from CDN when it needed [like in RequireJS](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn)? I mean specify external jQuery source (on CDN) somewhere in config and then use it in CommonJS (or AMD) style:

```
$ = require('jquery')
```

The problem is I have my custom script **above** the jQuery's CDN link and so I have '*can't find variable jQuery*' error. Schematically my code looks like:

```
<script src="custom_code.js'>
  // uncompiled source like:
  define(['jquery', '../../node_modules/baconjs/dist/Bacon.js'], function($, bacon) {
    console.log 'ok'
  });
</script>
...
<script src="//yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it also did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530254/webpack-and-external-libraries), and with the use of `require.ensure` I've managed to get it work. custom_code.js:

```
require.ensure(['jquery', '../../node_modules/baconjs/dist/Bacon.js'], function(require){
  var $ = require 'jquery'
  var bacon = require '../../node_modules/baconjs/dist/Bacon.js'

  $('.content').prepend('it works!')
});
```

and in webpack config I've added

```
externals: { jquery: "jQuery" },
```

In this case webpack will make additional request for compiled bundle with Bacon.js.

Still I wonder what will be if client loads Bacon.js **before** jQuery will be loaded from CDN?

Comment: I would very much like an answer to your last question: "Still I wonder what will be if client loads Bacon.js before jQuery will be loaded from CDN?"

It is the problem I am having.

Comment: Found it--The answer to that question is to use something like the `scriptjs` package.