# Exclude react from webpack bundle

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to exclude react from my bundle which is generated by webpack. Reason being, we have a global version of react available on the page so I'll be using that.

I have tried using the below, as suggested here [Webpack and external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530254/webpack-and-external-libraries) but this doesn't seem to work. I can see webpack has exported React but it still 
appears in the bundle.

```
externals: {
  'react': 'React'
}
```

I was thinking it may be another dependency e.g. react-router importing react? Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: Maybe it would help: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275

Comment: See this related issue. http://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/1726

Answer (score 44):

I had the same problem as you did. Was stuck for one night, found the answer, `react-dom` requires `react/lib/ReactDOM`, which still includes `react` in the bundle. Solution looks like this:

```
externals: {
 'react': 'react', // Case matters here 
 'react-dom' : 'reactDOM' // Case matters here 
}
```

Then add `react-dom` to the script tag in your page.

Comment: Thank you. In my case is was `react-dom`: `react-dom` that solved the issue.

Answer (score 20):

`webpack` config:

```js
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router': 'ReactRouter'
}
```

add these to the bottom of `index.html` body.

```js
<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/react/15.4.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/react/15.4.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/react-router/2.8.1/ReactRouter.js"></script>
```

and, in your `entry` file, maybe `index.js`:

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');

const App = () => {
    return <div>
        webpack externals
    </div>
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: And, you can inject `script` tag using some webpack plugin like `htmlwebpackplugin` or write a node/shell script to do this by yourself. But this is another question

Answer (score -3):

You can just create multiple entries to separate react from your application bundle. You can for example do the following, using the webpack CommonsChunkPlugin :

```js
module.exports = {
entry: {
    "app": "your app entry file",
    "react" : "react"
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("react", "react.bundle.js")
   ]
}
```